Efficiently return number of exact matches using data.table R
I have two large data.tables in R, the have exactly the same columns and structure. Table2 is substantially larger than Table1.
For each row in Table1 I need to count the exact matches present in Table 2. If there are more than 5 exact matches I want to randomly sample one of the matches, returning the row index. I need to do this as efficiently as possible.
This is what I've tried so far, but it returns an error.
match_indices <- Table2[Table1, on = names(Table1), which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L]
      
      if (length(match_indices) >= 5) {
        sampled_index <- sample(match_indices, 1) }

Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 30783947 rows; more than 1979212 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Any suggestions to get this working efficiently?

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

I presume one efficient approach could be to pre-process Table 2 to make a version that only includes one of each group when the group has more than 5 observations. Then it's just a join to that.

Simulate some data since none was provided.
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
Table1 <- data.table(id=1:10, matrix(sample(LETTERS, 30, TRUE), nc=3))
Table2 <- data.table(id=1:100000, matrix(sample(LETTERS, 300000, TRUE), nc=3))

Table2[Table1, on = names(Table2)[-1]][, n:=.N, by=i.id][
         n>5, .SD[sample(.N, 1)], by=i.id]

Gives
    i.id    id     V1     V2     V3     n
   <int> <int> <char> <char> <char> <int>
1:     1 90436      O      N      H     9
2:     2 93077      S      V      Z    12
3:     5 30703      J      E      I     6
4:     9 83073      E      I      Q     9
5:    10 72940      T      C      K     8

Where i.id is the original id in Table1 (the row index) and id is the index from Table2 that was randomly sampled. Thus, 5 of the original 10 rows from Table1 had more than 5 matches in Table2.
